# Platform for writing ebooks in open source manner

Tags: git, github

i'm looking for a platform for collaborating on the writing of a book.

Something like github for books ?

Any ideas on how to approach this would be nice.

Comment: What about using google docs ?

Comment: @aphex google docs is an option, although i was looking to leverage the power of VCS like git to collaborate just like open source projects. this way I think it scales up better and also not closed for the google docs platform only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm looking for a platform for collaborating on the writing of a book.

Are there any **real big** differences from collaborating on the writing code? I can't see any and I think, any good SCM will work in this area too.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, using github. But then I have to use a text format with rich content ability like `html`. Can't use `pdf` or `doc` because they are not text files... That means that I have to convert the `doc` file into an `html` file. Maybe it's worth it.

Comment: @Michael - use local (desktop) tools of authoring for writing content, use repository for SCM only.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sourcefabric.org/en/booktype/ seems to be aimed at this task. There's a [demo](http://booktype-demo.sourcefabric.org/) available.